# Dynamic Table in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am trying to create a dynamic table with a variable number of rows which will depend on the number of people in a specific account. So if there is one record with a secondary individual in the account there should be 2 rows but if there are n people, then there should be n rows plus the main individual populating the cells with merged information. This is a bit more advanced AMPScript than what I know so any suggestions, functions or approach will be really appreciated

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve. What about the table is dynamic? Every Table has n rows. Maybe you could outline what data you have and where do you need it. Also it sounds like maybe a SQL Activity could do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for something like this:
Description follows later.

```
%%[
var @i, @rows, @row, @individualID, @individualName, @rowsToReturn
var @customer, @tableCells

set @customer = [DataExtensionColumnName]
/* Up to 2000 Rows */
set @rowstoReturn = 0 
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("DataExtensionName" ,@rowsToReturn, "Individual-ID asc", "CustomerNumber",@customer)

]%%

<table>

%%[
for @i = 1 TO RowCount(@rows) DO
]%%

    <tr>

/* depending how many cells you want in each row, i made it with 2 */   
%%[
    set @row = Row(@rows,@i)
    set @individualID = Field(@row, "Individual-ID")
    set @tableCells = Concat('<td>',@individualID,'</td>')

    set @row = Row(@rows,@i)
    set @individualName = Field(@row, "name")
    set @tableCells = Concat('<td>',@individualName,'</td>')
]%%
    %%=v(@tablecells)=%%
    </tr>
%%[ 
next @i 
]%%

</table>
```